# Does Redis Snapshot restores expiration value after restore from snapshot dump?

Tags: redis, replication, snapshot, data-recovery

Question 1:
Does Redis snapshot only take backup of key-values or key expiration value as well?

Question 2:
We have a shared Redis cluster with 1 master and 2 slaves replication. 
(2 projects uses the same cluster with different purposes)
Is it possible to only take a snapshot of some keys or does Redis snapshot takes backup of all datasets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, expiration timestamps are stored in the snapshot (RDB) file and are loaded when recovering from it
2. No, there isn't and sharing a database between apps isn't considered good practice in Redis (unless the apps share information). Split to two independent databases instead, and you'll be able to backup (and configure) each without any regards to the other.

Comment: Thanks Itamar. Here (https://redis.io/topics/cluster-spec), it says"Redis Cluster does not support multiple databases like the stand alone version of Redis. There is just database 0 and the SELECT command is not allowed."

Comment: In such case, snapshotting for individual database will not be possible, right?

Comment: Independent means separate processes, you can install two clusters on the same servers.